# The configuration file has been changed by another program in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I am working in C# Windows Form Application. I am using 2 forms for my application. And I have one *app.config* file to save the settings run time.

I have a button in my Form1 to open the Form2. I have some settings to be saved in the Form2 as well as Form1.

I made my app running. While running I updated a setting in app.config through Form1. After that I clicked on the button to open the Form2 and made some modifications and tried to save the settings to the same app.config file. But it threw an exception saying

> The configuration file has been changed by another program.

I couldn't figure it out where I went wrong. Please help me to make it work.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:
This is the function I have in the form 1

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        config1.AppSettings.Settings.Add("no_of_cameras", null);
        config1.AppSettings.Settings["no_of_cameras"].Value = (no.Value).ToString("G");
        config1.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
    }
```

And this is the function in my Form 2:

```
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        config2.AppSettings.Settings.Add("mail_enable", null);

        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            label1.Show();
            textBox1.Show();
            config2.AppSettings.Settings["mail_enable"].Value = "true";
            config2.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        }
        else
        {
            config2.AppSettings.Settings["mail_enable"].Value = "false";
            config2.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            textBox1.Hide();
            label1.Hide();
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
    }
```

Comment: if just its about saving data to file I would suggest you use `XML` file. Show your code.

Comment: Thank you @RohitGupta. But I don't have time. So do I have any method to do it in app.config itself?

Comment: You are saving your config after updating it right ? `config.save()`

Comment: You should use  `Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();` after you modify the value in form1 and do the form2 code

Comment: yes @RohitGupta I have a button to save the modified data. And I am using config.save() function to save it

Comment: Thank you @prasy for your instant reply. I tried the above code. But still I am having the same problem.

Comment: @Dhivakar: can you post your code here so, that people can help you by going through ur code.

Comment: @prasy I have added my code above. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: @prasy I have added my code above. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: @Dhivakarkanagaraj: Hope the below code helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Save(), you need to destroy the configuration object and recreate it for multiple save operations to work normally. See the below code.

Form 1 Code :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (Configuration config1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None))
  {
    config1.AppSettings.Settings.Add("no_of_cameras", null);
    config1.AppSettings.Settings["no_of_cameras"].Value = (no.Value).ToString("G");
    config1.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
   }
}
```

Form2 Code:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (Configuration config2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None))
  {
    config2.AppSettings.Settings.Add("mail_enable", null);

    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        label1.Show();
        textBox1.Show();
        config2.AppSettings.Settings["mail_enable"].Value = "true";
        config2.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    }
    else
    {
        config2.AppSettings.Settings["mail_enable"].Value = "false";
        config2.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        textBox1.Hide();
        label1.Hide();
    }

    Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
  }
}
```

Comment: Configuration is not IDisposable, so why the using statement?

Answer (score 0):

Form 2 cannot overwrite the app.config since it is still being used by Form 1 (or vice-versa). So you need to nullify the Configuration variable after saving.

The using statement doesn't work since Configuration is not an IDisposable.

Form 1:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Configuration config1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

        config1.AppSettings.Settings.Add("no_of_cameras", null);
        config1.AppSettings.Settings["no_of_cameras"].Value = (no.Value).ToString("G");
        config1.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
        config1 = null;
    }
```

Form 2:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Configuration config2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

        config2.AppSettings.Settings.Add("mail_enable", null);

        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            label1.Show();
            textBox1.Show();
            config2.AppSettings.Settings["mail_enable"].Value = "true";
            config2.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        }
        else
        {
            config2.AppSettings.Settings["mail_enable"].Value = "false";
            config2.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            textBox1.Hide();
            label1.Hide();
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
        config2 = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you was saved what you need , you need destroy , add :
`Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();`